# AWS Lambda does not execute the promises without await

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda, axios

I have the following handler for my AWS Lambda function. I don't want to or need to wait for `Promise.all` resolve or reject. Because, I am not interested about its result. My purpose is to just send those requests and finish.
The problem is that if I remove the `await` keyword (pointed with an arrow), the requests are not firing up. But, if I put the `await` keyword, the Lambda function needs to run and be charged for 3-5 seconds, and it is not cost effective for me.

Could you explain what I am doing wrong? Why the requests are not being sent without the `await` keyword?

```js
module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    const urls = [/*some API urls*/];
--> await Promise.all(urls.map((url) => {
      return axios.post(url, { email })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }));

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'OK' }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'INTERNAL_ERROR' }),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Do you know for sure that your various POST requests were not actually made before the Lambda terminated?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html)

> If your code performs an asynchronous task, return a promise to make sure that it finishes running. When you resolve or reject the promise, Lambda sends the response or error to the invoker.

If you don't return a promise, there is no guarantee your async tasks will run to an end. With making the handler `async` you are indeed returning a promise. But without `await`ing the `Promise.all` this promise from the handler is immediately resolved, and thus execution of your lambda (and all unfinished async tasks) is stopped.

And this seems quite logical. Otherwise everybody would write the heavy lifting computations in an async task which runs for a long time. And the only synchronous call in the lambda function would be calling that async task and the lambda function would return after (and be charged for) only a few milliseconds.

If you want to pay only for a 100ms, make your task fast enough. If you task takes 4 seconds, you have to pay for 4 seconds.

Comment: There is no computation! Just sitting idle and waiting for a response is not considered computation. Why can't I choose not to wait?

Comment: That doesn't matter. Once the eventhandler returns (or the promise returned by the eventhandler isn't pending anymore) execution of the lambda (and all unfinished tasks) is stopped. Eventhough waiting for a http request may be no heavy computation, it still needs resources to be scheduled (cpu time, io bandwidth ...)