# how to force a AWS Lambda to complete all the code

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a lambda that is inserting a record into an Airtable db.  This should be pretty straight forward and I have it working locally.

Once I put it into Lambda the record is not inserted.  I have been messing with this for 2 days and can't figure out why the record won't load into Airtable.

The only other note that matters is that this lambda is long polling for SQS messages.

```
console.log('Loading function');
const Airtable = require('airtable');
const apiKey = process.env.AIRTABLE_API_KEY;
const BaseTable = process.env.AIRTABLE_BASE_TABLE;
var base = new Airtable({
  apiKey: apiKey
}).base(BaseTable);
const table = base('Contacts');


exports.handler = async (event) => {
  for (const {
      messageId,
      body
    } of event.Records) {
    console.log("iteration: " + iteration);
    const data = JSON.parse(body);
    var fields = {
      "Full Name (First Middle Last)": data.firstname + ' ' + data.lastname,
      "Email": data.email,
      "Phone": data.phonenumber,
      "Address": data.address_one + ' ' + data.address_two,
      "City": data.city,
      "State/Province": data.state,
      "Postal Code": data.zip,
      "Country": data.country,
      "Birthday": data.dob,
    };
    insertRecord(fields);
  }

  console.log('before the end');
};

function insertRecord(fields) {
  console.log('insert Record');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    table.create([{
      fields: fields
    }], function(err, records) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR');
        console.log(err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        console.log('SUCCESS');
        resolve(records);
      }

    });
  });

}
```

I have been googling, and reviewing, others' answers for multiple days now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Lambda does not execute the promises without await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66853109/aws-lambda-does-not-execute-the-promises-without-await)

Comment: You are not awaiting `insertRecord`